# Where's the source for org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.*?

Tags: eclipse, java

I cannot successfully attach the source for the classes in the org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.* package to my Eclipse environment.

In an attempt to isolate a possible deadlock bug in openjdk's pulseaudio classes I had to find the source for the icedtea pulseaudio package. Naturally the first resort was to install the openjdk-8-source package then point Eclipse to the src.zip file which is installed.

This worked fine for the common JRE packages like java.io.* etc, however the needed org.classpath.* path were not in this zip - or at least not where they would be expected by Eclipse. (I haven't traversed every single directory in that zip)

Is this code from a non-openjdk author? Who is the author so I may file the bug?

Ubuntu 16.04
JRE packages used in Eclipse: openjdk-8-jdk, openjdk-8-source
Eclipse 4.6.2 ( not from repos )

Answer (score 2):

The sources are available here: http://icedtea.classpath.org/hg/icedtea-sound/file/tip

You can file bugs at http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi

I would also suggest disabling the provider entirely. Edit `jre/lib/sound.properties` and comment out the PulseAudio providers. OpenJDK should fall back to the built-in alsa provider (which redirects to PulseAudio anyway).